# Reconnecting 50 amp service to outbuilding

Tags: electrical

I replaced a barn that had buried 50 amp service from the main house electrical. Before the old building was demoed, I removed the breaker box. I know it needs to be regrounded, as the old building was. That part is easy. What I need need to know is how to reconnect the breaker box removed from the old building to the wires safely. Three wires and a ground. Wire nuts aren’t going to cut it. How do you spice 1/4”+ solid copper wires?

Comment: Where will you be doing this splicing? In the dirt? In a junction box inside?  Were the old wires cut off by the demo company?

Comment: I cut the pvc, with the wire inside, at the concrete of the old building. There is about 4’ of pvc connected to the breaker box and about 2 feet of wire sticking out of the ground. Concrete is scheduled to be poured next month.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture would help us better understand your question. If you can't edit it into your question, edit the URL, and someone will be along to edit the picture in.

Comment: Your splice needs to be in a junction box.  The junction box needs to remain accessible for the life of the building, "accessible" means you don't need any tools to get to the cover of the box, it can't be buried behind concrete, drywall, anything like that.

Comment: A screwdriver is a tool and every j box I install requires a cover, but I agree it must be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

### You'll need a *pull box* and some insulated mechanical ("Polaris") connectors for this

You are correct that wire nuts and an ordinary junction box won't cut it here.  Instead, what you need is a correctly sized(6" by 6" minimum unless you have fatter conduit than 1", which will require you to go up to 9" by 9") *pull box* rated for the environment (NEMA 1 for inside, NEMA 3R for outside) to house the splices, and then insulated mechanical connectors (Polaris/Unitap/...) rated for the gauge of wire in question to make the splices.  You'll also need to use a torque wrench to make up the connections -- we're talking torques on the order of 10-20 ft-lbs here.  Last but not least, you cannot bury the box -- it must remain accessible so that the next bloke who needs to mess with those splices can go in and do so without having to demo part of the building on a junction-box hunt.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why electrician’s estimate was $1400 for this job.

Comment: Polaris are great but a little spendy, but if you figure the time tape and split bolts they are well worth it.+   DJK, as for the cost look up Hoffman boxes, plus the cost of fittings connectors, driving a new rod and things add up fast, if allowed you could do it much cheaper but working with used stuff has pitfalls, 1400 may not be that high but pricing is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You would have done better to have pulled out the wire on the old building and coiled it up until the new building was built - no splice needed.

Now you need an **accessible junction box** (which must **remain accessible** "after concrete is poured") to make the connection in. That box must be of sufficent size for the number and size of wires you are joining.

As for your main question, the usual answer is "**split bolts**" which any electrical supply or well-stocked hardware store electrical section will have.

[image: Split bolt connector]

Then you need to insulate them with suitable tape, which needs to be outdoor & wet-location rated if the junction box is outside. "Self-fusing" is a typical descriptor for suitable tape (it "fuses to itself" to make a waterproof seal which lasts.) Scotch 2155 is one example (not a product recommendation, there are other suitable tapes from other manufacturers.)

Comment: It's probably easier to use Polaris connectors for this job (no need to worry about fiddly taping with those, unlike split bolts).  He may also need a pull box instead of  a normal j-box depending on wire gauge.

Comment: Split bolt would be fine for the ground wire.  I would use insulated lug terminals for the conductors.  Torque em and you're done.  Taping up bulky split bolts as conductors would be a nightmare.

Comment: The wire gage is 3X 8 with a 12 gage ground (3mm & 2mm approx.) the existing wire coming out of the ground will not reach to where the top of the concrete will be. Can I bury the Polaris connectors? It looks like I will need two splices.

Comment: Also, if the ground wire goes back to the main house panel is a ground rod really necessary?

Comment: A **ground** at the building is absolutely necessary. A **ground rod** may not be, if you correctly prepare the concrete you are about to pour to provide a UFER Ground. You cannot "bury" (inaccessibly) any connectors - if you cannot provide an accessible connection, you need to replace the wires, or cut (the conduit only, NOT the wires) back to a location outside the building where you can provide an accessible pull box for the junction to be located in. Or just cut a foot or two from the conduit to allow access in a junction box that is set in the floor, with an access plate at floor level.